# Why there are not that much really good Java eCommerce applications?

Tags: e-commerce

Lot of PHP, Perl ones, but very few Java apps? Most of existing ones are very old and use old technologies.
Java is only eCommerce platform as to me ;)

Comment: Silly question as it stands.  If you are looking for a list of Java eCommerce applications then please restate.  Also, 'good' is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Kind of a broad generalization, no?

Answer (score 1):

I think java has a higher barrier to entry than php and perl.  It requires a lot more infrastructure to get something working.  Php, you just need apache and mod_php.  Same with perl.

Answer (score 0):

As per Gary, and most hosting providers provide Apache and PHP as a standard part of the package.